# How to handle invalid data errors?

Tags: javascript, angular, echarts

I need a way to handle invalid data on [echarts](https://echarts.apache.org/).

```
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
      type: 'radar'
    }
  ]
};
```

For example, the radar chart does not work with an array of numbers as data. I want my app to tell me, on runtime, that the data is invalid. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add in the Types ([Found here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/echarts)) So your data will look like this:

```
option: echarts.EChartOption = {
    ...
    series: [
        {
            data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
            // Would highlight the line above and throw and error on runtime too.
            type: 'radar'
        },
        ...
     ],
};
```